# Troubling shooting after combining two python scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my first code. Using this code I extracted a list of (6800) random elements and saved my results as a text file. (The file that this code is reading from has over 10,000 lines so every time I run it, I get a new set of random elements).

```
 import random
 with open('filename.txt') as fin:
   lines = fin.readlines()
   random.shuffle(lines)
   for i, line in enumerate(lines):
      if i >= 0 and i < 6800:
         print(line, end='')
```

Here is my second code. Using that saved text file from my previous step, I then use this code to compare the file to another text file. My results are as you can see, is the count; which always varies, e.g 2390 or 4325 etc..

```
import csv    
with open ("SavedTextFile_RandomElements.txt") as f:
   dict1 = {}
   r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
   for row in r:
       a, b, v = row
       dict1.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

#for key in dict1:
    #print(key[0])
    #print(key[1])
    #print(d[key][0]])

with open ("filename2.txt") as f:
   dict2 = {}
   r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
   for row in r:
      a, b, v = row
      dict2.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

#for key in dict2:
    #print(key[0])

count = 0
for key1 in dict1:
   for key2 in dict2:
       if (key1[0] == key2[0]) and abs((float(key1[1].split(" ")[0])) - (float(key2[1].split(" ")[0]))) < 10000:
           count += 1

print(count)
```

I decided to combine the two, because I want to skip the extracting and saving process and just have the first code run straight into the second having the random elements read automatically. Here is the combined two:

```
import csv
import random

with open('filename.txt') as fin:
   lines = fin.readlines()
   random.shuffle(lines)

str_o = " "
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
   if i >= 0 and i < 6800:
       str_o += line

  r = str_o
  dict1 = {}
  r = csv.reader(fin,delimiter="\t")
  for row in r:
     a, b, v = row
     dict1.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

with open ("filename2.txt") as f:
  dict2 = {}
  r = csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")
  for row in r:
     a, b, v = row
     dict2.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)

  count = 0
  for key1 in dict1:
     for key2 in dict2:
        if (key1[0] == key2[0]) and abs((float(key1[1].split(" ")[0])) - (float(key2[1].split(" ")[0]))) < 1000:
          count += 1

 print(count)
```

However, now when I run the code. I always get a count of 0. Even if I change (less than one thousand):

```
 < 1000:
```

to for example (less than ten thousand):

```
 < 10000:
```

I am only receiving a count of zero. And I should only receive a count of zero when I write of course less than zero:

```
 < 0:
```

But no matter what number I put in, I always get zero. I went wrong somewhere. Can you guys help me figure out where that was? I am happy to clarify anything.

**[EDIT]**
Both of my files are in the following format:

```
 1  10045   0.120559958
 1  157465  0.590642951
 1  222471  0.947959795
 1  222473  0.083341617
 1  222541  0.054014337
 1  222588  0.060296547
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: My indentation is fixed in IDLE. When i copied the code over here, things got thrown off a little. I will fix it though @wwii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanted to combine the two codes, so you really don't need to read from SavedTextFile_RandomElements.txt, right?

In that case you need to read from somewhere, and I think you intended to store those in variable 'r'. But you overwrote 'r' using this:

```
  r = csv.reader(fin,delimiter="\t")
```

BTW, was there a typo there 2 lines above that line? You didn't have any file open statement for 'fin'. The above combined code must have not been able to run properly (exception thrown).

To fix, simply remove the csv.reader line, like so (and reduce indentation starting dict1={}

```
r = str_o

dict1 = {}
for row in r:
    a, b, v = row.split()
    dict1.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)
```

**EDIT: another issue, causing ValueError exception**
I missed this earlier. You are concatenating the whole file contents into a single string, but you later on loops over r to read each line and break it into a,b,v.

The error to unpack comes from this loop because you are looping over a single string, meaning you are getting each character, instead of each line, per loop.

To fix this, you just need a single list 'r', no need for string:

```
r = []
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if i >= 0 and i < 6800:
        r.append(line)

dict1 = {}
for row in r:
    a, b, v = row.split()
    dict1.setdefault((a,b),[]).append(v)
```

**EDIT: Reading 'row' or line into variables**
Since input file is split line by line into string separated by whitespaces, you need to split the 'row' var:

```
a, b, v = row.split()
```

Comment: See I figured that I was overwriting 'r' But the problem is that if i remove `r = csv.reader(fin,delimiter="\t")` I get a valueerror `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` So I am confused about how to solve this problem @Maelstrom

Comment: Can you elaborate, which line did you get that error on?

Comment: Python is not showing me which line the error is on. But when I remove `r = csv.reader(fin,delimiter="\t")` I get `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` However when I put it back, I get `0` as my result. I think my problem is what you suggested; that I am overwriting 'r' But how can I alter my code to fix that? @Maelstrom

Comment: OK. I think the other problem is the 'r' or 'str_o'.

Comment: I am running into another value error which now says `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)` Are these errors a result of my files? @Maelstrom

Comment: Could be. Without looking at the content of your file, it's hard to say. Does your file have lines with at least 3 values separated by comma?

Comment: Up above i've provided an example of how both of my files are formatted. They each consist of three columns separated by tabs. @Maelstrom

Comment: See my EDIT above. You need to split each line into a list so you can read it into a, b, v.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me on this. That solved the problem @Maelstrom

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell where exactly you went wrong.  In your combined code:

- You create `str_o` and assign it to `r` but you never use it
- A few lines later you assign a `csv.reader` to `r` - it is hard to tell from your indentation whether this is still within the `with` block.

You want to be doing something like this (I didn't use the csv module):

```
import collections, random
d1 = collections.defaultdict(list)
d2 = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('filename.txt') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()
    lines = random.sample(lines, 6800)
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        try:
            a, b, v = line.split('\t')
            d1[(a,b)].append(v)
        except ValueError as e:
            print 'Error:' + line

with open ("filename2.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        try:
            a, b, v = line.split('\t')
            d2[(a,b)].append(v)
        except ValueError as e:
            print 'Error:' + line
```

Comment: I fooled around with your suggestions. However, in line 16 of the code I keep getting another valueerror `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack` Does this mean the problem is my file? @wwii

Comment: @SamWilliams - that error means that at least one of the lines when split only produces 2 items.  You could put a ```try/except``` block around it and print the offending line or count those lines.  Maybe there are some blank lines?  see edit.